# How to find a function that satisfies $\displaystyle\frac{\mathrm df(x)}{\mathrm dx}=\frac{f(x)}{x}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How to generally find a function that satisfies $$\frac{\mathrm df(x)}{\mathrm dx}=\frac{f(x)}{x}?$$

I can "guess-and-verify" that $f(x)=ax$ (for $a\in\mathbb R$) is one such function. How do I know if this is unique?

Comment: the average of a function would be $\frac{\int_0^x f(x)dx}{x}$, not $\frac{f(x)}{x}$.

Comment: @insipidintegrator: sorry for the confusion. I meant a function that satisfies the mathematical equality shown.

Comment: $$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac1x$$ which implies $$\ln |f(x)|=\ln|x|+C$$ or $f(x)=ax.$

Comment: Why the down votes?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: this is not the most general solution. For instance $|x|$ is also one.

Comment: $|x|$ is not differentiable at 0...

Comment: @Gregory: where is it written that it has to be ?

Comment: Considering that the equation satisfies $f'(x) = f(x)/x$ - without the OP stating explicitly it would seem natural that it should hold for all $x \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: @Gregory: this is an "automatic" assumption from the theory of ODE's. But it is nowhere stated here. In fact, nothing is known about $f$ at $0$. That makes a more interesting question.

Comment: @YvesDaoust $f(x)=|x$ isn't differentiable everywhere. If we restrict any differentiable equation to a disconnected domain, we can do piece-wise solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your differential equation is linear.  The solution space theorem tells us that for a linear homogeneous equation of order $n$, there are $n$ independent solutions.  Because your equation is first order, there can only be one family of solutions parametrized by initial condition, which is what you have found.

Comment: The equation has a singularity at $x=0$ hence it is not perfectly linear.

Comment: There is a unique solution that is differentiable at zero where $a__= a_+$.

Comment: This is an example of a removable singularity.

Comment: That's right, but differentiability at the origin is not asked. As written, the equation is not valid at $x=0$.

Comment: I suppose.  But if the problem included a clause like, "for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$", then we would require a unique solution.

Comment: This is a technicality that I'm not super familiar with.  Perhaps @ThomasAndrews can give some insight.

Comment: $\frac{f(x)}x$ is not defined at $x=0$, so you may not write $\forall$.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is a differential equation and can be solved as it is separable:
$$ f'(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x} \implies \frac{df}{f} = \frac{dx}{x}. $$
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables for details.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Your transformation of the equation mus be guarded with $f(x)\ne0$.

Comment: Not true. The equation is valid. Substitute $f(x) = ax$ into the equation - the singularity you describe is removable.

Comment: Division by zero is undefined. and you may not multiply the members of an equation by zero.

Comment: Would you have said the same thing if the equation was written $xf'(x) - f(x) = 0$? Removable singularity.

Comment: I see no singularity there.

Comment: In any case, the function having a removable singularity does not mean that $\frac{f(0)}0$ is defined.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=x\,g(x)$, and notice that $x=0$ is not allowed. The equation becomes

$$g(x)+x\,g'(x)=g(x)$$ or

$$g'(x)=0.$$

Obviously a solution is $g(x)=a$, but as the function is not defined at $x=0$, the general solution is

$$\begin{cases}x>0\to f(x)=a_+x\\x<0\to f(x)=a_-x.\end{cases}$$

---

In this solution, we used the so-called method of the variation of the constant (making $a$ a function of $x$). But there is a lot more theory and techniques about these "ordinary differential equations".

Comment: This downvote is a shame.